# windows randomly unable to restart or shutdown after prolonged usage

Tags: windows-10, shutdown, reboot, error-logging

I have a problem with my PC being unable to shutdown or restart after prolonged usage.

I enabled verbose mode during boot / shutdown / restart and I can see the system looping very fast through shutdown messages and then after the ffinal message "Stopping Services", it gets stuck on "Shutting Down" or "Restarting" forever.

A few times I left it like that overnight for 12 hours+ and it didn't manage to restart or shutdown. After I reset the PC and work for a few minutes I can restart / shutdown fine without any issues. Sometimes I can restart after a week of usage, but sometimes it won't after 2-3 days of usage.

I'm trying to detect why this is happening but I don't see anything useful in my logs.

This is very important for me because when I  it happens I have no choice but to hold the power button to force power off the PC or reset it. This in turn causes my software mirror raid to fail and resync. This in turn for 4TBs makes my PC unusable for a whole day.

For now I'm stuck to leaving my PC on pretty much forever until it forces me to restart due to an update because I need it usable during the day.

I would like to completely troubleshoot the issue without formatting or reinstalling windows  and I've taken pretty much every action I could find online.

SFC  shows everything is OK

DISM shows everything is OK

chkdsk shows everything is perfect.

Removing all usb devices before shutdown/restart has no effect whatsoever. 
Exiting all apps I can see in task manager except background processes has no effect whatsoever.

Unfortunately windows doesn't seem to have a really verbose mode to actually show what it's trying to do at that phase unlike linux and I want to find a way to detect that.

Any ideas how to proceed and troubleshoot the issue?

In windows event viewer in System all I can see as error is

```
The server Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_1.13.0.18932_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy!CortanaPlaces.PlaceStore did not register with DCOM within the required timeout.
```

There is also a warning

```
The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Launch permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
Windows.SecurityCenter.SecurityAppBroker
 and APPID 
Unavailable
 to the user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM SID (S-1-5-18) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.
```

In applications logs I can only see this error but the logging times don't match with the shutdown and restart period.

```
Faulting application name: GLCRIconSvc.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 

0x5a25299e
Faulting module name: CFGMGR32.dll, version: 10.0.18932.1000, time stamp: 0x104b0664
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000babd
Faulting process id: 0x13f8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d538077d3c768b
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\genestor.inf_amd64_312a8313e431fea0\GLCRIconSvc.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\CFGMGR32.dll
Report Id: 1605c249-da64-4fe8-8418-c03e83e1c142
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

And a warning

```
Certificate for local system with Thumbprint aa 3b 29 ac 3f c8 89 e1 4f bb 63 83 4a 65 da 28 03 30 92 29 is about to expire or already expired.
```

Here's my system info

[image]

Comment: Are you able to rollback to the stable 1903 release, since you are currently, on the Slow Insider Review branch for 19H2?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to roll out to the stable release as I need the advanced features of WSL2 for my work needs. However I've had this problem since 1903 got released. I don't think it would help much